# TypeORM not recognizing migrations path

Tags: node.js, typescript, database, typeorm, ts-node

I'm trying to create migrations for my application in typeorm, but I'm getting the error

```
No changes in database schema were found - cannot generate a migration. To create a new empty migration use "typeorm migration:create" command
```

However, the migrations folder is properly configured in the database config and also with the "npm run migrate:generate" command within my package.json

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.2",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.13",
    "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.15",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "pg": "^8.8.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.11",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
  "name": "networking_api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist & tsc",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec ts-node ./src/server.ts",
    "migration:generate": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs -d ./src/database/config.ts migration:generate ./src/database/migrations/default",
    "migration:run": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs -d ./src/database/config.ts migration:run"  
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.11.15",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  }
}
```

src/database/config.ts

```
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "postgres",
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: 5433,
    username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    synchronize: true,
    logging: true,
    entities: [`${__dirname}/../entities/*.{ts,js}`],
    migrations: [`${__dirname}/migrations/*.{ts,js}`],
});
```

Comment: You are setting synchronize to true in your DataSource, so the typeorm will not find the difference on the schema to generate the migration. Restart your db, set `synchronize: false` and `migration: true`and try again.